# Apply ignored/interesting tags to the StackExchange questions list

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, tag-watching, ignored-tags, linked-accounts

(as option) using the tags of the respective site's accounts.

Comment: Do they even share tags?

Comment: @Michael: no, that's why I say "the respective site's accounts"